# Save config file at two locations automatically

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a frontend and backend project and some config data both projects needs to use e.g. max_image_upload_size or max_post_text_length. Both projects are in javascript (react and aws lambda) and I'm using visual studio code.
Whenever I'm editing my config file I'd like it to be saved inside both projects automatically. Anyone has an idea how I can do that?

Comment: use a symbolic link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coudnt accept rioV8's comment as answer so here is the answer:

Use a symbolic link.